# Create a Document Library from a Template using SharePoint Online PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

How do I create a new document library from an existing document library saved as template using SharePoint Online PowerShell?

I was trying the following:

```
New-PnPList -Title "Test" -Template DocLibTemplate.stp -Url Test
```

I had no luck on CSOM PowerShell... PnP seemd to be the best option available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following PowerShell for your reference.

```
$ListTemplateInternalName="DocLibTemplate.stp"
$ListName ="PnpDocument"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://xx.sharepoint.com/sites/lz -Credential (Get-credential)

$Context = Get-PnPContext
$Web = $Context.Site.RootWeb
$ListTemplates = $Context.Site.GetCustomListTemplates($Web)
$Context.Load($Web)
$Context.Load($ListTemplates)
Invoke-PnPQuery

$ListTemplate = $ListTemplates | where { $_.InternalName -eq $ListTemplateInternalName }

if ($ListTemplate -eq $null)
{
    Throw [System.Exception] "Template not found"
}

$ListCreation = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListCreationInformation
$ListCreation.Title = $ListName
$ListCreation.ListTemplate = $ListTemplate

$Web.Lists.Add($ListCreation)
Invoke-PnPQuery

Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

Comment: your example is pretty good! it help me to get my own working, I changed everything to purely use PowerShell CSOM, thanks for your help!